# NGINX and log rotation: is missing log entries possible?

Tags: nginx, log-files, mv, log-rotation

In it's simplest realization, one can implement NGINX log rotation as following:

```
mv access.log access.log.0
kill -USR1 `cat master.nginx.pid`
```

**My question.** Do we have a concurrency issue here? I mean, if NGINX writes a log entry between two actions (1) file was renamed and (2) it got a command to reload, could some of log entries be just lost?

Comment: if it helps to you, please mark the answer as complete

Comment: @mikhailov Sure. Tnx for helping out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before send USR1 signal wait for 15 seconds and you will see that *access.log.0" is still being used. It happens because log is open for write access based on inode, not the file name. So it is concurrent-safe to use this technique: mv + USR1